# Perl module depends on a binary, why tests fail on FreeBSD even if using CheckBin?

Tags: perl

I'm made a **Perl module** (Qiime2::Artifact) that heavily relies on the '`unzip`' binary to 
work[1].

The module's here: https://metacpan.org/pod/Qiime2::Artifact

To declare the dependency I used the CheckBin plugin for Distzilla:

```
[CheckBin]
command = unzip
```

That results in this section in Makefile.PL:

```
# inserted by Dist::Zilla::Plugin::CheckBin 0.008
use Devel::CheckBin;
check_bin('unzip');
```

The problem is that the tests are failing in FreeBSD (and possibly other platforms, I only test under Linux and Darwin): http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Qiime2-Artifact+0.10.5
And it looks like it's unzip the problem, apparently the binary is not there, or at least I can tell that executing 'unzip' returns non zero.

1) Naive question: is unzip not commonly available under BSD or is there another explanation?

2) More important question: Why is the CheckBin module not preventing the installation/test? Or is it working and the binary is indeed there and I'm missing something *else*?

Thanks for any advice / guidance.

[1] I checked some Perl modules to avoid directly executing unzip, but none was providing the whole set of features (like piping to stdout a single text file of the archive) or the performance needed.

Comment: See also [Alien::unzip](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::unzip)

Comment: On UNIX platforms _gzip_ and _bzip_ is more common. Usually you have to install _unzip_ as additional package. Most systems does not require compression utilities and very often you will not find these binaries pre-installed in minimal OS systems.

Comment: Not having 'unzip' is a legitimate condition of a system, what I really don't understand is why "CheckBin" isn't preventing the installation. Lack of 'unzip' is not just limiting some features (in that case I could skip some tests), it's preventing any use of the module, that's why I'd like to understand what should I do here: just skipping tests is not enought for me, I want the module not to install at all.

Comment: It seems the problem is not that unzip is missing, or as you say, it would exit during the configure phase. Instead unzip is not returning a 0 status when you first test it during construction.

Comment: As a side note, I would recommend passing your commands as a list to `system`, not a string. You are improperly quoting them, you would need to use String::ShellQuote to correctly quote an arbitrary filename for bourne shells, but it's easier to use the list form of system and avoid the shell entirely. `my @cmd = ('unzip', '-p', $self->{filename}, $file); ... system(@cmd)`

Comment: You also might like [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3).

Comment: You could try using Archive::Zip, it has a method to [extract a zip member directly to a filehandle](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip#extractToFileHandle(-$fh-)), like STDOUT.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful suggestions, I really appreciate them.
I'm still curious in understading what is wrong with BSD, maybe when I'll have some time I'll try a VM  :)

Comment: I suspect it is that FreeBSD has a different unzip, as [documented here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=unzip&sektion=1). Unlike the `unzip` available on my linux machines, it does not show any valid syntax to call `unzip` with no arguments, as your constructor test does.

Comment: Among the reasons to avoid archive::zip is that is hard to install on macOS Catalina. As most xs modules. But I might reconsider this eventually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the precious hints received from  you all (special thanks to @Grinnz), it appears that:

- `unzip` is commonly found in BSD but a different flavor ships
- `CheckBin` was indeed working, it's just the binary itself behaving in an unexpected way (specifically exiting with non-zero status if invoked, quite annoying even if not unseen I must say)

Final comment:
 - `Archive::Zip` is a good hint, but I will not adopt it as Alien modules are getting harder to install under MacOS. I might change my mind and just put them in miniconda that greatly helps in sorting this problem out.